# Should I choose a "Pass" grade instead of a letter grade due to the study disruption during the Covid-19?

Tags: gpa, canada, covid-19

I understand this question has been asked in this forum. But I still want to have some advice on my case.

I am current a research master student in one of the top universities in Canada. In the last semester, I got two B+. This gives me a GPA of 3.3 which is lower than the PhD admission requirements of 3.5. Now, due to Covid-19, our school allows us to choose to report a Pass in our transcript instead of a letter grade. Students choosing this Pass/Fail option will not have their GPA obtained in this semester counted towards their final GPA. That means if I can obtain a GPA higher than 3.5 in the next semester, I can still satisfy the PhD admission requirements. So should I choose this Pass/Fail option if I am considering the opportunity of apply for PhD programs? Thanks.

Comment: Some places are more "flexible" with their entry requirements so how can we answer this? And even others might be CV19 aware...

Comment: What is the downside of choosing the pass/fail option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I take an S/NS grade during COVID19 if I want to go to grad school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149161/should-i-take-an-s-ns-grade-during-covid19-if-i-want-to-go-to-grad-school)

Comment: Also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/147022/should-i-be-worried-about-low-undergraduate-grades-during-the-covid-19-crisis-af

Answer (score 0):

You can choose “Pass” if you want but everyone will understand you made this choice to preserve your average, so your file will still look bad admission to a PhD program.

With “Pass” you may technically qualify to apply but I doubt admission into a PhD is simply a matter of meeting the technical requirements. Regardless of what you choose, you need to do better next term, so you can establish that this past term was just a one-off due to COVID.

On a related matter: are you sure you can still choose between “Pass” or a grade?  For most students the window to make that choice closed with or near the end of exams (at the latest).

Comment: Why shouldn't one be able to chose this after.the exam?

Comment: @user111388 in some cases you could but there was a cut-off date long passed.

Comment: So all exams in Canada have already passes a long time ago?

Comment: @user111388   yes the end of classes was in early April or somewhere around then.  They start in early January and go for 14  weeks there so exams are usually done by 3rd week of April (modulo some late exams).

Comment: Okay, interesting! In my countrily, exams are done after the end of the classes in June or July.

Comment: "Your file will still look bad" what are you basing this on? If anything I doubt a reasonable admissions committee will forget about COVID disruptions when they see 2020 next to the P/F grade.

Comment: Not sure I follow your comment.  I also doubt an admission committee will forget COVID, i.e a PASS would look suspicious on a transcript.